# "curb your enthusiasm" any special meaning

Tags: meaning

Regarding the show "Curb your enthusiasm" - does the title indicate some more meaning than simply "restrain your enthusiasm"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The wording of the show's title certainly brings to mind the many "Curb Your  Dog" signs found in New York City and other urban areas.  Perhaps they exist in affluent west Los Angeles,   where most of the shoe is set.

To *curb one's dog* is

> To lead (a dog) off the sidewalk into the gutter so that it can excrete waste.

([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/curb))
It also means to clean up after your dog or cat has pooped in a public area.

I doubt that this usage of curb escaped the attention of Larry David when he came up with the title for his series. I doubt, however, that the sign's (and phrase's) meaning has  much, if anything, to do with how the show's title is meant to be explicitly  understood. But Larry David is a creative genius, and there is no way he was unfamiliar with the phrase "Curb Your Dog." As dry a sense of humor as the guy has, I would not be surprised if the well-known saying *curb you dog* did not play some small part in the phrasing of the show's title, if only as (ironic?) self-deprecation.

Wikipedia claims to say something intelligent about the title:

> David has explained the show's title in TV interviews as reflecting his perception that many people seem to live their lives projecting false enthusiasm, which he believes is used to imply that "they are better than you." This conflicts with his dry style. The title also urges the audience not to expect too much from the show; at the time of the premiere, David wanted to lower expectations after *Seinfeld*'s phenomenal success.

Comment: excellent - thanks for going into many aspects to explain it.